# Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:preDebugBuild'. In React Native

Tags: android, react-native

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:preDebugBuild'.

> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not resolve com.facebook.android:facebook-core:[5.0,6.0[.
> Required by:
> project :app > project :react-native-fbsdk
> > Skipped due to earlier error
> Could not resolve com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[5.0,6.0[.
> Required by:
> project :app > project :react-native-fbsdk
> > Skipped due to earlier error
> Could not resolve com.facebook.android:facebook-share:[5.0,6.0[.
> Required by:
> project :app > project :react-native-fbsdk
> > Skipped due to earlier error
> Could not resolve org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.+.
> Required by:
> project :app > project :react-native-inappbrowser-reborn
> > Skipped due to earlier error

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 44s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

PS C:\Users\karan\Desktop\react-grocery-customer-master>

I am facing this issue